# Who was removed?

Tags: support, reputation, users

I got -76 reputation points today: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/16193?tab=reputation

Who is he/she? Just curious.

Answer (score 2):

*not an answer, just a long comment*

but it was a surprise to see JanDoggen leave and delete all content on this site

https://stackexchange.com/users/241731/jan-doggen

Thanks Jan for all your efforts to keep a high standard on this site!

Answer (score 1):

OMG, https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/4293/jan-doggen

Comment: wow, I was thinking it was going to be a bot or scam account. Curious how you figured this out.

Comment: I just visited https://opendata.stackexchange.com/review